# make laravel report malformed JSON

Tags: json, exception, laravel

Is there a way to make laravel report a malformed JSON on input? Now the controller just doesnt receive any data and I would want it to raise an exception if content type is json on request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in a before filter:

```
App::before(function ($request)
{
    if ( ! str_contains($request->getContentType(), 'json')) return;

    json_decode($request->getContent());

    if (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        throw new Exception('Malformed JSON.');
    }
});
```

---

If you don't want it to fail when there's no content, use this:

```
App::before(function ($request)
{
    if ( ! ($content = $request->getContent())) return;

    if ( ! str_contains($request->getContentType(), 'json')) return;

    json_decode($content);

    if (json_last_error() != JSON_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        throw new Exception('Malformed JSON.');
    }
});
```

Comment: is this normal, that getContentType is just 'json' not 'application/json' ? I dont get past the check

Comment: anyway, I added additional check for 'json' and it worked, so I accept your answer